# django-axes not saving ip-address

Tags: django

I have a django app running behind gunicorn+nginx. These packages are installed:

```
django-axes              6.0.5
django-ipware            5.0.0
```

This is my config:

```
AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT = 5
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = 1
AXES_IPWARE_PROXY_COUNT = 1
AXES_IPWARE_META_PRECEDENCE_ORDER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',)
AXES_LOCKOUT_PARAMETERS = [["username", "ip_address"]]
```

`request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')` returns my ip-address. If I test it on dev server it saves 127.0.0.1 but in production ip address field stays empty. What am I doing wrong?